# Chome console .click() working on one website, but not on another website. Why and how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-console

When I open Facebook's [messenger.com](http://messenger.com) and run `document.getElementsByClassName('_1htf')[2].click();` in the console, it jumps to a conversation and opens it. `_1htf` is a random class that I picked, every conversation entry contains this class.

Doing the same on [web.whatsapp.com](http://web.whatsapp.com) to access a conversation, nothing happens. I can't even `click()` the "real" buttons on this website.

I don't really understand why this works on the first, but does not work on the second website.

There are 2 differences between the websites that I was able to point out:

- `web.whatsapp.com` blocks the browser's right-mouse button context menu and overrides it with a custom one - `messenger.com` doesn't do that
- `messenger.com`'s `_1htf` elements contain an `URI` that leads to the conversation (you can open the uri in a new tab and end up in the conversation) - **`web.whatsapp.com`'s elements do not contain a link but somehow still open the conversation when clicked**

How is this achieved? Is there some Javascript listening to mouse events? **If so, how can I trigger the event? I really need to "click" the conversation programmatically.**

This is how one conversation entry looks in `web.whatsapp.com`

```
<div class="infinite-list-item infinite-list-item-transition" style="z-index: 200; height: 72px; transform: translateY(144px);">
    <div tabindex="-1" class="chat-drag-cover">
        <div class="active chat hover">
            <div class="chat-avatar">
                <div class="avatar icon-user-default">
                    <div class="avatar-body" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="https://dyn.web.whatsapp.com/pp?t=s&amp;u=4 . . . " draggable="false" class="avatar-image is-loaded"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-body">
                <div class="chat-main">
                    <div class="chat-title"><span class="emojitext ellipsify" dir="auto" title="CONVERSATION PARTNER"><!-- react-text: 92 -->CONVERSATION PARTNER<!-- /react-text --></span></div>
                    <div class="chat-meta"><span class="timestamp">21:16</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-secondary">
                    <div class="chat-status"><span class="last-msg" title="CONVERSATION MESSAGE"><span class="emojitext" dir="ltr"><!-- react-text: 28843 -->CONVERSATION MESSAGE<!-- /react-text --></span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chat-meta"><span></span><span></span><span class="context-container"><div data-icon="down" role="button" class="img btn-context" style="width: 20px; opacity: 1;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 21 21" width="21" height="21"><path fill-opacity=".31" d="M4.8 6.1l5.7 5.7 5.7-5.7 1.6 1.6-7.3 7.2-7.3-7.2 1.6-1.6z"></path></svg></div></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update: I tried to trigger numerous events listed in Chrome Dev Console > Elements > Event Listeners but non of that seems to work, it only outputs `ƒ focus() { [native code] }` but doesn't jump to the conversation.

Thanks

Comment: it's certainly possible that they're detecting that it isn't a real user interaction, but, it's more likely that the target elements are in a separate frame or some other similar cause of it not working. Start by making sure `document.getElementsByClassName` actually contains your target element.

Comment: It definitely does. I can print its contents and it's throwing me a `cannot read property` when I add a typo to it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome console click() not working on Chat List in web.whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115835/chrome-console-click-not-working-on-chat-list-in-web-whatsapp)

Answer (score 2):

Whatsapp probably blocks untrusted clicks.

To see what I'm talking about, first type this into the console:

```
document.onclick = (e) => { console.log(e.isTrusted) };
```

Now, try clicking anywhere on the page. It should show `true` in the console now.

If you try doing something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();
```

then `isTrusted` will be false, since it's not a real click.

As far as I know, you can't spoof the value, so you'll have to find out a different way to do what you want (try inspecting any click/mousedown event handlers on what you're clicking, and see if you can call some functions directly).

Comment: Chrome's console has a section that can help with this when you select an element. All of it's event handlers will be listed on the right, thus allowing you to find the click handler and potentially gain access to it if possible, or duplicate it if not.

Comment: `document.onclick = (e) => { console.log(e.isTrusted) };` does NOT output anything on the whatsapp website. It does, however, on the messenger website. Thanks a lot for bringing this to my attention. Trying to override/spoof the value now hahahah

Comment: Well... you can't, it's a read-only property. I'm looking into whatsapp to see if I can find anything though.

Comment: Haha mate I was just joking with the spoofing thing. What I am working on right now is to find every occurrence of `isTrusted` in the JS and deleting it/ setting it to true. It also occurs like 5 times in the code near the encryption stuff but it's like 5 occurrences each so that wasn't too hard. The problem is that even after deleting these (and saving the files), your first code still doesn't fire the output. I will go over my changes again and check

Comment: Yo I think I made it, will hopefully not forget to update

Comment: Ok, kinda progress here: There is a line containing `if(v._enabled){` in the `vendor1` file and removing  it enables `document.elementFromPoint(615, 215).click();` to get an event triggered (clicked a picture, thank god that picture was there in the chat). Idek why I tried this, it isn't even the first call but when doing what I said, it somehow works for a bit. Will keep you posted

EDIT: Nvm, still doesn't work for conversations

Comment: FOUND IT!!! I FINALLY GOT IT HAHAHAHA. Will post about it soon. Key was not to focus on click() because this event gets handled but is totally irrelevant for the container.

Comment: Nice!­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: @user2875404 can you post what you have tried and working?